# download a file using apache http

Tags: java, download, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was trying to download a zip file from a page which requries username/password to access ( html form based authentication). I am using apache http library for it.
Earlier I had worked on something very similar, that page required just password to download the file.
Here is my code

```
     DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
                        public URI lastRedirectedUri;

                        public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, 
                                                    HttpResponse response, 
                                                    HttpContext context) {
                            boolean isRedirect = false;
                            try {
                                isRedirect = 
                                        super.isRedirected(request, response, 
                                                           context);
                            } catch (org.apache.http.ProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (!isRedirect) {
                                int responseCode = 
                                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                                if (responseCode == 301 || 
                                    responseCode == 302) {
                                    System.out.println("the original response code is" + responseCode);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                            return isRedirect;
                        }

//                        public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
//                                    throws ProtocolException {
//
//                                lastRedirectedUri = super.getLocationURI(request , response, context);
//
//                                return lastRedirectedUri;
//                            }

                    });


            List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           // formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", arg[1]));
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "*****"));
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "****"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity1 = 
                new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
            HttpPost httppost = 
                new HttpPost("https://*************************/l/?next=/s/48750/d/");
               // new HttpPost(arg[0]);
            httppost.setEntity(entity1);


            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContextConfigurer.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
            HttpHost target = 
                (HttpHost)localContext.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
            System.out.println("Final target: " + target);


            System.out.println(response.getProtocolVersion());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            FileOutputStream fos = 
                                new java.io.FileOutputStream("download.zip");
                            entity.writeTo(fos);
                            fos.close();
            }
```

if you open the url provided in the code you will find the form has two parameters by the name email and password , and I have supplied them as formparams ( values commented in the code above ).
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems ok, what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any erros, when I check the "download.zip" file into which i am writing the output stream , its just a 4kb file (which is not expected ). I changed the extension of this zip file into html and opened in a notepad , it is a page same as the login page ( with email and password fields) , though not exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BasicAuthentication.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Authentication_Schemes
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Examples

Comment: HttpClient allows Basic Authentication, but the question is looking for html form based authentication.

Comment: httpclient also supports form based authentication. I have worked with a similar program before. Two differences in this program and the other program i had worked with before are: 1) The page in this program uses two form parameters instead of one 2) This page is secure (https) - i noticed this just now.